# What does a single number mean when passed as parameter 'breaks' in an R histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

I am learning to plot histograms in R, but I have some problem with parameter "breaks" for a single number. In the help, it says:

```
breaks: a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram
```

I did the following experiment:

```
data("women")
hist(women$weight, breaks = 7)
```

I expect it should give me 7 bins, but the result is not what I expected! It gives me 10 bins.

[image]

Do you know, what does `breaks = 7` mean? What does it mean in the help "number of cells"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading carefully `breaks` argument help page to the end, it says:

> **breaks**
>    one of:
>
> 1. a vector giving the breakpoints between histogram cells,
> 2. a function to compute the vector of breakpoints,
> 3. a single number giving the number of cells for the histogram,
> 4. a character string naming an algorithm to compute the number of cells (see ‘Details’),
> 5. a function to compute the number of cells.
>
> **In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only**; the breakpoints will be set to pretty values. If breaks is a function, the
>   x vector is supplied to it as the only argument.

So, as you can notice, `n` is considered only a "suggestion", it probably tries to get near to that value but it depends on the input values and if they can be nicely split into `n` buckets (it uses function [`pretty`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/pretty.html) to compute them).

Hence, the only way to force the number of breaks is to provide the vector of interval breakpoints between the cells.

e.g.

```
data("women")
n <- 7
minv <- min(women$weight)
maxv <- max(women$weight)
breaks <- c(minv, minv + cumsum(rep.int((maxv - minv) / n, n-1)), maxv)
hist(women$weight, breaks = breaks)
```

[image]